# Add Windows Server 2008 MPIO futures to Windows 7

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, fibre-channel, multipath

I have interest issue.

I want to work with SAN storage via two Fibre Chanel with using multypath. And I want to use Windows 7 as workstation. Can i add this futures to Windows 7. And how to do this? May be I can copy some files from Windows Server 2008 and/or change the entries in the registry?

Answer (score 2):

MPIO is not supported on Windows 7 - and this site's for professionals, who typically wouldn't consider hacking around in the way you suggest. Could you not just use Server 2008 with the whole 'Desktop Experience' stuff switched on instead?

Comment: Ok. it's good position, but guys from Microsoft forum do not agree with you... http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_update/i-want-to-use-mpio-with-ms-iscsi-initiator-how-to/fac32233-1517-4d0c-9155-dde111ae1a83

Comment: @Cucumber I wouldn't say they do not agree with me, firstly that question is about iSCSI MPIO, a much easier scenario than FC, secondly the MS guy redirects the question elsewhere and one other guy says it kind of worked "after countless tries" and says he "wouldn't suggest doing it" - so I really don't understand your point.